# What is the history of the semidirect product?

Tags: group-theory, math-history, semidirect-product

It's not hard to imagine early group theorists getting the inspiration for the semidirect product because after you've seen a few examples of finite nonabelian groups, the pattern starts to emerge on its own.

But who first codified the definition, explicitly proposed looking at a mapping $\varphi :H\to Aut(N)$, and showed that $\langle n, h\rangle\langle n', h'\rangle = \langle n\varphi_{h}(n'), hh'\rangle$ gives a group operation on the product set $N\times H$, and when?

I'd be interested in any leads on any part of this: earlier prefigurings and special cases; later distillations; who coined the name; etc.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but note that it is exactly the same as the action of the derivative (cocycle) of a smooth map on the tangent bundle (and so quite old, and not only appearing in group theory). Although someone like Hadamard studied geodesics on the manifold (that is, their projection) and not on the tangent bundle, all computations had to be done on the tangent bundle.

Comment: Sorry, I know so little about the derivative of a smooth map on a tangent bundle that I can't see why they are the same or how this relates.  I would be glad for a pointer or a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Like this: if $f\colon M\to M$ is a smooth map on a manifold $M$, for each $(h,n)\in M\times T_hM$ we define $A(h,n)=(f(h),d_hfn)$. This is what I call the derivative cocycle. To compare write $f(h')=hh'$ and $d_hf=\varphi_h$. In this case $N$ would be $\mathbb R^p$ if $M$ is $p$-dimensional.

Comment: I have had a look at "Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics"(http://jeff560.tripod.com/d.html): alas, they have no entry for "semi-direct product"

Comment: Complement: in dynamics many other groups are considered besides ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb R^p)$... This was only a very simple example. :)

Comment: I have found a 1963 occurrence of the word "semi-direct" applied to the domain of cristallography:(http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1963RSPTA.255..216A), but I would bet that the concept has emerged before WWII.

Comment: And to be clear: You're only interested in the "homomorphism into automorphism group" point of view? Because the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem on semidirect products was proven by Zassenhaus in 1937. However, I'm willing to bet quite a lot that Burnside used *something* equivalent to semidirect products (in his 1897 book, something about whether two groups are "permutable" is said, a bit after he defines direct products. I can't tell, but I think he might be giving an old definition for a semidirect product).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not sure what I'm interested in because the history is so murky and I've had so little success finding anything at all. I'd like as much material as possible.

Comment: Does "mapping" mean "homomorphism" nowadays?

Comment: This would perhaps have a better chance of being answered on [hsm.se].

Comment: In my experience, that is not the case.

Comment: Progress report: in pursuing this question I have been slowly working my way through Burnside's 1897 _Theory of Groups of Finite Order_. If the semidirect product was known then, one would expect to find it there. It is hard to be sure, because Burnside's terminology is so different from modern terminology, but **so far** I have found nothing like a semidirect product, even in the places I would expect to. For example, Burnside constructs the holomorph of a group, but the construction is very 19th-century and does not appear to involve a semidirect product.

Comment: @MJD This question has been on my backburner for quite some time. I would imagine that if his construction yields the same holomorph we use today, there's (at least the germ of!) a semidirect product hiding in there somewhere. But as you said, the differences in terminology make progress *quite* the struggle.

Comment: @pjs36 It is the same holomorph, but it's constructed in a different way.  I'd have to check to be sure, but remember that for Burnside everything is a permutation group, so it often makes sense to form the union of two sets of elements that today we would consider quite different things. I think for the holomorph Burnside takes $G$ and then considers $G'$ as the Cayley representation of $G$.  The elements of $G'$ are permutations of the elements of $G$, and then he forms the union with $Aut(G)$ whose elements are also permutations of the elements of $G$.  ...

Comment: ... The group operation on the union is simply composition of permutations, and the holomoprh is the closure of the union with respect to this operation.  No doubt there is a way to view this _as_ a semidirect product but it seems clear to me that Burnside _didn't_ view it that way.  He certainly doesn't mention it as being a special case of any sort of semidirect product construction.

Comment: Notes to self: 1. I tried to use Google Books to find the earliest mention of the _term_ “semidirect product”. There were many false positives (e.g. in volume 100 of journal X which started in 1885) and I have not yet found anything really early.  The term does not appear in Zassenhaus 1949 “Theory of Groups” or Kurosh 1960 (“Theory of Groups” 2.ed vol 1).

Comment: 2.   But Zassenhaus (p94). says: “The extension problem posed _and solved_ by Otto Schreier reads: ‘Given two abstract groups $\mathfrak N$ and $\mathfrak F$, find all groups $\mathfrak G$ which contain $\mathfrak N$ as a normal subgroup, such that ${\mathfrak G}/{\mathfrak N} \simeq {\mathfrak F}.$’  (italics mine)  It seems impossible that Schreier's solution of this problem could fail to contain a fairly complete and modern development of a semidirect product. You should see what Zassenhaus has to say about this problem. Schreier died in 1929.

Comment: 3. [MacTutor biographies says](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Schreier.html): “Schreier's doctorate, supervised by Philipp Furtwängler, was awarded for a thesis _Über die Erweiterung von Gruppen_ (“On extensions of groups”) on 8 November 1923. In this work he tackled a very fundamental group theory problem that had been posed by Otto Hölder: Given two groups $G$ and $H$, find all groups $E$ having a normal subgroup $N$ isomorphic to $G$ such that the factor group $E/N$ is isomorphic to $H$.”  I think they mean “quotient group”, not “factor group".

Comment: Kurosh 1960 also discusses the extension problem, on pages 76 and following.

Comment: @MJD A search in Google books should also include at least French and German translation, since the English one is maybe not the original one. For sure it appears in Bourbaki around 1939 ("produit semi-direct").

Comment: @MJD "factor group" is very common to mean "quotient group" in old papers.

Answer (score 2):

This question, who invented the semidirect product (and, the holomorph for that matter) , interested me for a long time, too. Two people might be good candidates: G.A. Miller and O. Hoelder. Miller wrote papers on the holomorphs of cyclic groups early in the 1900's and he was a contemporary of Hoelder (a pioneer in considering automorphisms).

Comment: Sorry about the earlier comment. I misread the question. Some others misread something else. Welcome to Math.SE!